# Integrate sharepoint calendar appointments directly to outlook & other email clients

Tags: outlook, lotus-notes

The scenario I am looking here may need some customization but here is the question.

Whenever an entry or record is added to sharepoint calendar, I would like the same event (or appointment) to appear in their email client (Such as outlook, lotus etc).

Currently I am able to send out to the email client but the user has to open it and accept it. We would like it to be added directly to the users calendar in their email client (outlook, lotus etc).

Answer (score 2):

[Nintex Workflow](http://nintexdownload.com/Nsupport/NW_Edition_Comparison_Table_English.pdf) has an action in the Enterprise license that will create a meeting/appointment in a user's Exchange calendar.  Look at the Exchange Server Integration section.

Out of the box, it isn't going to be possible.  If a third party tool isn't an option, then you'll need to construct your own workflow activity or code to do it.

I have used Nintex Workflow to build ICS files and attach them to emails send to people so they can add them to their calendars when using custom lists and not calendar lists.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I am looking to have the appointment directly added to their calendar either through third party tool or custom coding? Is it possible? Users are not supposed to (and not required) to open and accept to add it to their calendar.   Please clarify.

Comment: Nintex Workflow Enterprise will automatically add the calendar event to the user's Exchange calendar without any intervention on their part.

Comment: Is it possible through customization or coding? Are there any examples or suggestions on this? thanks.

Comment: With the Nintex workflow activity Eric mentions, you wouldn't need any custom code. If you want to code it yourself, you could write a workflow activity that hooks into Exchange, gets the Calendar for the user in question and adds the item.

Comment: Are there any code examples available that people have done? Also does Nintex does it for Lotus notes apart from outlook?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and no, Nintex does not have a Lotus Notes action.  That being said, that have a pretty good SDK and you might be able to roll your own custom Lotus Notes action.

Comment: I will take a look at Nintex. As far writing custom code approach, I do not know how to make it automatically get embedded to lotus calendar. I will keep looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

We have been developing an Outlook Add-in to accomplish this. ProperSync, can connect a SharePoint calendar directly to an Outlook calendar. Either your personal calendar or a different calendar you specify. If this is interesting, you can find more at www.propersync.com.

*Disclaimer - I do work for ProperSync and hope this is a helpful suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know if it does with Lotus notes as well? I am looking for both outlook & lotus. thanks